# How do I split strings with \e metacharacters in perl?

Tags: perl, split

I need to split strings from a variable where the delimeter may be one of three characters:

`;` -or- `,` -or- `\e`

I can escape the `;`, but escape `\e` is giving me fits.

Data looks like:

`joe@gmail.com,joe@xyz.com,joe@isp.net`

`fred@123.com;fred@gmail.com`

`suzy@yahoo.com\esuzy@abc.com`

I start by matching some strings, if true place the data in an array, splitting on whatever delimeter matches:

```
if($ax=~/abc.com|xyz.com|123.com/) {
  my @addr=split /[\;,\\\e]/, $ax;
  ...
}
```

Output in this scenario gives me:

```
'joe@gmail.com',
'joe@xyz.com',
'joe@isp.net'

'fred@123.com',
'fred@gmail.com'

'suzy@yahoo.com',
'esuzy@abc.com'  <--- Note the 'e'
```

Regex gives me anxiety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\e` is not a character, it's an escape code that represents a character. If your text contains literally `\e` then that's two characters, and a character class (the part in `[]`) can only match one character, in this case it matches the backslash.

You can use an alternation to match multiple strings of arbitrary length:

```
/[;,]|\\e/
```

Comment: Appreciate you pointing out '\e' is two characters. However, your answer does nothing different than what I was doing.

Comment: @sarge no, `perl -ne 'print join "\t", split /[;,]|\\e/, $_' your_data` will not print `esuzy` with `e` as your version (`/[\;,\\\e]/`) does.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running following code, and it gave output as expected :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @x = (
    "joe\@gmail.com,joe\@xyz.com,joe\@isp.net",

    "fred\@123.com;fred\@gmail.com",

    "suzy\@yahoo.com\esuzy\@abc.com"
);

foreach (@x) {
    my @array = split /[;,\e]/, $_;
    print Dumper(\@array);
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'joe@gmail.com',
          'joe@xyz.com',
          'joe@isp.net'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'fred@123.com',
          'fred@gmail.com'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'suzy@yahoo.com',
          'suzy@abc.com'
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks, and you're right, it does work. Thanks @Grinnz

Comment: This is different from the problem in OP because `\e` in a double quoted string contains the literal escape character, rather than the two characters \ and `e`. Thus the literal escape character in your character class also matches it.